# Could an object orbit a person's body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, estimation

Imagine you were on a spherical spacecraft that had equal mass all the way around and you were deep in space, away from the gravitational pull of any planetary bodies or stars. If you released a marble at arm's length, would it be gravitationally pulled toward your body? If you flicked it in one direction, would it begin to orbit you? (If a marble is too big, then maybe a grain of sand?)

Comment: Sure. Did you try to estimate the numbers?

Comment: Thank you, I would, but I'm just learning physics, and I don't know where to start. Below, Niels mentions it would be very slow and very weak, but how do we know that? I think I understand how to calculate orbital speed, but not the rate of attraction. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) For instance, if the mass of a person is 90kg, then the gravity "put out" by that person 90*6.673e-11, and I can do the same thing with the marble, but how does that tell me how fast that marble will fall toward the person? Any direction or resources are appreciated. All my extant examples tend to assume we're talking about earth, and Gravity is usually given as a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would. But because the force of gravity between objects as small as these is very very weak, the orbital speed of the marble would be very very slow and it would take not much of a kick to cause that marble to escape the influence of your gravity. Take @Qmechanic's suggestion and try plugging in some numbers to the equation to see for yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please point me to which equation I need? I can calculate orbital speed, acceleration, and period, but none of those has the mass of the satellite (the marble.)  So I can't calculate the rate of attraction. So if I calc. gravity as mass*6.673e-11, then I can calc. gravity for both the mass and the marble, but how does that tell me how fast that marble will fall toward the person? Any direction or resources are appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: you will probably find everything you need on the wikipedia page for gravity. give that a try and see.